# How to enable CKFinder 3.0 with CiviMail on CiviCRM 4.6.6

Tags: civimail

Problem: I cannot get CKFinder 3.0 to work on the CiviMail module. It is currently working in other CiviCRM modules, such as; events.

Installation:
Drupal 7.38
CiviCRM 4.6.6
CKFinder 3.0

I have successfully installed CKFinder and completed steps 1-3 from the [CiviCRM wiki](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC40/Adding+CKFinder+with+Authentication+to+CiviCRM), with exception to 3.d. There is a note at the top of the page that says: " This documentation refers to an older version of CiviCRM (3.4 / 4.0). View latest version." I have been unable to find updated documentation for how to install CKFinder into CiviMail on CiviCRM 4.6.6. I have RTFM, but I cannot figure this out =(

Please help! It is greatly appreciated.